# How can i use enum to pass variables between two scripts?

Tags: c#, enums, unity-game-engine

The first script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WallsTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum WallsInfo
    {
        Position, Length
    };

    // using a GameObject rather than a transform
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Vector3 wallsStartPosition;
    public float width = 0;
    public float height = 1;
    public float length = 2;
    public Camera wallsCamera;

    void Start()
    {
        wallsCamera.transform.position = new Vector3(wallsStartPosition.x, wallsStartPosition.y + 100, wallsStartPosition.z - 235);

        WallsInfo.Position = wallsStartPosition;

        BuildWalls();
    }
```

Then in another position i will want to use the WallsInfo.Position
But i'm not sure if passing variables using enum is a good idea ? And how to do it ?

The line:

```
WallsInfo.Position = wallsStartPosition;
```

Give me error:

The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

And i also want to pass the variable length using Length

Comment: what is `wallsStartPosition`? could you put it in your question ?

Comment: @osmanRahimi wallsStartPosition is the start position i set in the editor in the inspector. For example it's now 250,0,250 i don't set/init it in thr script only in the editor.

Comment: you can not set value to `WallsInfo.Position `, it's an enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an enum here you need a class or a struct. I bet an struct because it can't be null.

```
public struct WallsInfo
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public float Length { get; set; }
};
```

Enums on the other hand are used to store a collection of constant named values that are mapped to numbers for better organization. For example if you want to keep track of if a character is boy or a girl. Then you can just put an int and say 1 means boy 2 means girl in your head or you can do:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Boy = 1
    Girl =2
}
```

Then it's easy to have a character who can store boy or girl like

```
var gender = Gender.Boy;
```

Comment: This is should be working the problem i see now that is the second script that need to get this values is executing first so the info he get is empty. Position is 0,0,0 and Length also 0.

Comment: You should assign values to it. The new struct you created is a Type just like a normal `int` or `string` you just create one with the needed values and pass it to the other script. Unity handles this very cleverly you create a `public WallsInfo Walls` in your first script, fill it with the values and access it in other script using `script1instance.Walls`